# Undefined property: SimpleMagento\\Custom\\Controller\\Test\\First\\Interceptor::$getRequest ....... In controller

Tags: magento2, database, custom, post-data

Error in controller :- Undefined property: SimpleMagento\Custom\Controller\Test\First\Interceptor::$getRequest .......While fetching data from custom form. Can someone provide me solution or how to fetch data from custom form to controller ... Magento 2

Or else how to fetch data from custom form and store it to the custom table in DB.

Answer (score 1):

somwhere in the class `SimpleMagento\Custom\Controller\Test\First` there is this:

`$this->getRequest` instead of `$this->getRequest()`.  Missing `()`

Answer (score 0):

Seems, you have using the code `$getRequest` at `SimpleMagento\Custom\Controller\Test\First`. `$getRequest` wrong variable if you want to get form posted data at this URL.

**Then you have to use**

`$this->getRequest()` instead of `$getRequest`

Use `$this->getRequest()->getParams()` for getting All fields value, this `getParams()` give value in key-value format

Also `$this->getRequest()->getPostValues()` can use. Donot forgot to get do compile